# How to write the Lagrangian in terms of a projection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, tensor-calculus

We know that 
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu}-\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} \partial^{\nu} A^{\mu}\right)
$$

But how do we write the Lagrangian in the following way:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\,A^{\mu} P^{T}_{\mu \nu} \partial^2 A^{\nu}$$

in which $P^{T}_{\mu \nu}$ is the projection tensors.

Comment: Just to complete the question, you should write down what is $P_{\mu\nu}^T$ explicitly.

Comment: @prahar: I suspect that $P_{\mu\nu}$ is what Zhougruo is wanting

Comment: A first inspection makes me think this is not possible without introducing a gauge condition, such as $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$, in which case an integration by parts leads to $P_{\mu\nu}=-\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 2):

The second formula (where an overall minus sign is missing) is obtained using the product rule and discarding total derivatives. On the level of the action, it's just integration by parts assuming that surface/boundary terms vanish with fields decaying sufficiently fast at infinity. Thus:

$$L = -\frac{1}{2} (A^\mu g_{\mu\nu} \partial^2 A^\nu - A^\mu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu) = -\frac{1}{2} A^\mu \partial^2 (g_{\mu\nu} - \partial_\mu \partial_\nu/\partial^2) A^\nu $$

The projection is thus

$$P_{\mu\nu}^T = g_{\mu\nu} - \frac{\partial_\mu \partial_\nu}{\partial^2} \; , $$

where $\partial^{-2}$ is a formal way of expressing the Green function of the wave operator (or d'Alembertian), $\partial^2$. The kernel of $P_{\mu\nu}^T$ consists of gradients, $P_{\mu\nu}^T \, \partial^\nu \Lambda = 0$. This guarantees the (Abelian) gauge invariance of the Lagrangian: Adding a gradient to $A^\mu$ leaves $L$ unchanged.

Comment: You are right, I miss a minus sign.